# Is it really necessary for formula of transfer entropy to contain its past?

Tags: entropy, information-theory, mathematical-statistics

I'm studying transfer entropy these days and have some questions about it.

From the wiki, Transfer entropy is defined as
TE(X→Y) = H(Yt∣Yt−1:t−L) − H(Yt∣Yt−1:t−L,Xt−1:t−L).

As we can see in the formula, since past components of X of 2nd term in right hand side work as condition of entropy of Yt, we can tell whether X components influence uncertainty(entropy) of Y or not. If TE > 0, then past X components give some effect on entropy of Y and we may say that information flows from process X to process Y.(I feel like I'm speaking roughly)

In this point of view, is it okay to remove the condition 'Yt−1:t−L' in entropy calculation? 
As a beginner of this field, I think that 'H(Yt) − H(Yt∣Xt−1:t−L)' is enough to find out if information of past X flows to Y.

Help me please!!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your intuition is good. The term you defined is called the time-delayed mutual information, $I(Y_t ;X_{t-1:t-L}) = H(Y_t) - H(Y_t|X_{t-1:t-L})$ and is often used as a measure of temporal dependence.

Under what circumstances do we expect time-delayed mutual information to fail, while transfer entropy succeeds? Suppose $X_t$ and $Y_t$ are binary, set $L=1$. Suppose $X_{t\ldots}= 0,1,0,1,0,1,\ldots$ and $Y_{t\ldots}= 0,1,0,1,0,1,\ldots$ is identical to $X$. Now if you look at the time delayed mutual information, you will see that you get one bit. On the other hand, the transfer entropy will be zero bits. So one measure calls this strong temporal dependence and the other sees no temporal dependence. What is the intuitive difference here and why does it arise?

You can use $X_{t-1}$ to perfectly predict $Y_t$, and that's why the time-delayed mutual information is 1 bit. However, if you look at $Y_{t-1}$, you can also perfectly predict $Y_t$.  Because you can already perfectly predict $Y$ from its own past, knowing about $X$ doesn't add anything, and that's meaning behind the transfer entropy formula. It tries to prevent things like two temporal processes that repeat with the same frequency from looking correlated. Two clocks on different continents can have high mutual information, but no transfer entropy.